# Angular.js: ngSwitch to show/hide rather than add/remove DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

As I've recently found out, `ngSwitch` acts a bit like `ngIf`, in that it outright removes elements from the DOM rather than just hide them. Now in my application this strikes me as both needlessly expensive and potentially problematic down the line (if I need to access properties of my hidden DOM elements). At the same time I like the cleanliness of the `ngSwitch` syntax as opposed to a bunch of different `ngShow` directives (which would not allow me to include a 'default' behaviour either). Is there any way I can modify the way this directive works to have it merely hide elements, not remove them altogether? Thanks.

Comment: Well, technically you can since Angular is an open source project. But I would suggest against it, rather create your own directive that behaves the way you want.

Comment: Is this about Angular 2+ or AngularJS? Angular 2+ doesn't have `ngShow`, AngularJS doesn't have `ngSwitch`, `ngIf` AFAIK. Please make your question more clear. Angular (2+) itself doesn't provide anything like that. You can build one yourself though.

Comment: Sorry, AngularJS. Currently using v1.6.5. I was wondering if it was possible to do by setting up some parameter or if there was another directive I was unaware of, but if that's how it is then I'm probably better off creating my own.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understood better your need and I have the same need before.
I advice you to use ngSwitch with custom directives like this :

```html
<div ng-switch="mode">
  <directive-a ng-switch-when="a"></directive-a>
  <directive-b ng-switch-when="b">...</directive-b>
  <directive-c ng-switch-default>...</directive-c>
</div>
```

and in the definitions of your directives directiveA, directiveB and directiveC you use the templateUrl wich will use the cache from the second call of the directive.

The second approach is to use ng-show on every directive but I prefer the ng-switch because it let the dom lighter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I faced the same issue today and I managed to cache segments views by not using ngSwitch but directly the [hidden] attributes with the segment condition this way :

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segmentName">
  <ion-segment-button value="profile">
    Profile
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="friends">
    Friends
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
<page-profile [hidden]="segmentName != 'profile'" ></page-profile>
<page-friends [hidden]="segmentName != 'friends'" ></page-friends>
```

Just replace ngSwitchCase by the [hidden] conditional

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't any way to keep nodes hidden as ngShow and ngHide do if you use ngSwitch. Only the ngSwitchWhen node will be created if its condition is true, all others are commented.
The advantage of ngSwitch is that the dom will be lighter.

Comment: I see. I like the cleanliness of the syntax but am not still sure whether I can afford erasing and reinitialising entire components every time (I'm using it for a navigating tabs system and many of these have complex components that call back to the server or other stuff).

Comment: Instead of posting a new reply, you could just edit your original post next time.